# Codeigniter : How to change result array

Tags: php, arrays, api, codeigniter

How to change result array like this

[image]

to like this

[image]

this is my Controller

```
public function index(){

    $response = Requests::get('https://xsintern-api.learnbalance.com/api/users/');
    $responseData = $response->body; 
    $arrData = json_decode($responseData,true); 

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arrData);
    echo "</pre>";
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');

}
```

Comment: how the data coming now? object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**controller**

```
public function index(){

    $response = Requests::get('https://xsintern-api.learnbalance.com/api/users/');
    $responseData = $response->body; 
    $arrData = json_decode($responseData,true);
    $data = array(); 
    $data['arrData'] = $arrData;

    $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);

}
```

**view code**
First you need to set header then this

```
<?php foreach($arrData as $data){ ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $data['user_firstname'] ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in the HTML table

```
$data['arrData'] = json_decode($responseData,true);
```

Pass the data in the view `$this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);`

```
<?php foreach($arrData as $data): ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?= $data['user_firstname'] ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: It have error message like this  "  Message: Undefined variable: arrData  and Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: @wazowski I  have updated the anwser

Answer (score 0):

**controller**: First of all pass data to your view from your controller:

```
public function index(){

    $response = Requests::get('https://xsintern-api.learnbalance.com/api/users/');
    $responseData = $response->body; 
    $arrData = json_decode($responseData,true); 

    // Create an Data Array to store all the data
    // that you need to pass to your view
    $data['user'] = $arrData; 

    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);

}
```

**view**: Then in your view file create a table and make it dynamic to use the data that need to be shown:

```
<?php foreach($user as $key => $value) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $value['user_firstname'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $value['user_lastname'] ?></td>
    ...
    ..
    .
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the controller to pass the `$arrData` data :

```
public function index(){

    $response = Requests::get('https://xsintern-api.learnbalance.com/api/users/');
    $responseData = $response->body; 
    $data['arrData'] = json_decode($responseData,true); 

    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);

}
```

and try like this within the `welcome_message.php` view file :

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>The Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($arrData as $data): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $data['user_firstname'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```